# Why changing array variables item affects the array it has been inserted to in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, console

Here's some code:

```js
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [5,4];
var c = 6;
a.push(b);
console.log(a);
b[0] = 1;
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
a.push(c);
console.log(a);
c = 7;
console.log(a);
```

Here's the result in console:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, [ 5, 4 ] ]
[ 1, 2, 3, [ 1, 4 ] ]
[ 1, 4 ]
[ 1, 2, 3, [ 1, 4 ], 6 ]
[ 1, 2, 3, [ 1, 4 ], 6 ]
```

Can someone tell me why changing the first item of b array after pushing it to the a array also affects the a array here? For example when I change the value of c variable pushed to a array it doesn't affect the a array and that's what I want to happen with b as well.

Comment: To gauge your current understanding, how would you expect `b = [5,4]; c = b; c[0] = 1; console.log(b);` to behave?

Comment: console.log(b) should be [5,4] but I'm guessing it's gonna be [1,4]. But that's what I'm asking, why this happens?

Comment: Sure; I just wanted to make sure that your confusion wasn't related to `push` specifically, but applies more broadly to array references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects in javascript (like arrays) are passed around as references.  So, when you do:

```
a.push(b)
```

You are pushing a reference to `b` into the array `a`.  If you later change `b`, there is only one `b` so it will change in all places that refer to it, including in the array.

Another way to say this is that `a.push(b)` does not make a copy of `b`.  What was pushed into the array just points to the same `b` you've always had so if you change `b`, the reference in the array just points to the one `b` there is so looking at the value through the array will see the change too.

---

If you truly want a copy (that won't be affected by changes to the original) pushed into the array, you can make an explicit copy using `.slice()`.

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [5,4];
var c = 6;
a.push(b.slice());   // push a shallow copy of b
```

---

This is a fairly fundamental thing to grasp when learning javascript.  When you pass or assign objects in javascript (and an array is one type of object), a copy is not made.  Instead, you end up with more than one part of your code all pointing to the exact same object.  This is obviously a feature that can be taken advantage of, but it means that when you want an independent copy that has no connection to the original, you have to explicitly make a copy.

To contrast with this, primitives such as Boolean or Number are assigned or passed as a copy.

Comment: +1; fot additional guidance on `.slice()`, see [Copying array by value in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript)